# Creating sum of date ranges in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, date-range

I have the following DataFrame, with over 3 million rows:

```
VALID_FROM   VALID_TO  VALUE
0 2022-01-01 2022-01-02      5
1 2022-01-01 2022-01-03      2
2 2022-01-02 2022-01-04      7
3 2022-01-03 2022-01-06      3
```

I want to create one large date_range with a sum of the values for each timestamp.

For the DataFrame above that would come out to:

```
       dates  val
0 2022-01-01    7
1 2022-01-02   14
2 2022-01-03   12
3 2022-01-04   10
4 2022-01-05    3
5 2022-01-06    3
```

However, as the DataFrame has a little over 3 Million rows I don't want to iterate over each row and I'm not sure how to do this without iterating. Any suggestions?

Currently my code looks like this:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for idx, row in dummy_df.iterrows():
    dr = pd.date_range(row["VALID_FROM"], end = row["VALID_TO"], freq = "D")
    tmp_df = pd.DataFrame({"dates": dr, "val": row["VALUE"]})
    new_df = pd.concat(objs=[new_df, tmp_df], ignore_index=True)

new_df.groupby("dates", as_index=False, group_keys=False).sum()
```

The result of the groupby would be my desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If performance is important use [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for new rows, create `date` colun with counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and last aggregate `sum`:

```
df['VALID_FROM'] = pd.to_datetime(df['VALID_FROM'])
df['VALID_TO'] = pd.to_datetime(df['VALID_TO'])

df1 = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['VALID_TO'].sub(df['VALID_FROM']).dt.days + 1)]
df1['dates'] = df1['VALID_FROM'] + pd.to_timedelta(df1.groupby(level=0).cumcount(),unit='d')

df1 = df1.groupby('dates', as_index=False)['VALUE'].sum()
print (df1)
       dates  VALUE
0 2022-01-01      7
1 2022-01-02     14
2 2022-01-03     12
3 2022-01-04     10
4 2022-01-05      3
5 2022-01-06      3
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to build a list of dates, from the min to the max from the original dataframe, use a non-equi join with [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join)  to get matches, and finally groupby and sum:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

# build the date pandas object:
dates = df.filter(like='VALID').to_numpy()
dates = pd.date_range(dates.min(), dates.max(), freq='1D')
dates = pd.Series(dates, name='dates')

# compute the inequality join between valid_from and valid_to, 
# followed by the aggregation on a groupby:
(df
.conditional_join(
    dates, 
    ('VALID_FROM', 'dates', '<='),
    ('VALID_TO','dates', '>='), 
    # if you have numba installed, 
    # it may improve performance
    use_numba=False, 
    df_columns='VALUE')
.groupby('dates')
.VALUE
.sum()
) 
dates
2022-01-01     7
2022-01-02    14
2022-01-03    12
2022-01-04    10
2022-01-05     3
2022-01-06     3
Name: VALUE, dtype: int64
```